# Restrict which packages are installable from a repository

Tags: linux, apt, repository, deb

I have my official Debian repos (say `repo1`). Now I add a repo of the supplier from `package X` (`repo2`). Package X is not in the official Debian repos. Of course, `repo 2` can have some overlapping packages with `repo 1`, like `package Y`, some may be even never, and required for `package X` to run (`repo 1::package Y` has `version 1.0`, `repo 2::package Y` has `version 2.0`).

I want to know, when a package other than `package X` is installed from `repo 2`. Preferably even blocking any package from being installed from `repo 2`, to avoid it messing up my system.

My current idea is to restrict `repo2`, so that only `package X` is installable from there, but I have no idea, how to do that.

Why I may want this:

- I may not fully trust `repo2`, and I want to keep track of the packages originating from there
- if there are packages, other than `package X` coming from `repo2`, and I do not allow those to be installed, it will break `package X`, but that is no problem, I can decide at that point if I allow those packages from that source, but I will have a heads-up of what is happening

**Basically I want `apt` to tell me, if anything other, than `Package X` is installed from `repo 2`.**

---

Some solutions I considered:

apt-pinning:

- I think won't work, because if `package X` requires `version 2.0` of `package Y`, and `repo1` has `version 1.0`, `repo 2` will be used, regardless of pinning

tweak the `Packages.gz` from `repo 2`:

- I have no idea, how could this be implemented

Comment: You are requesting us to help you ending in dependency hell. You even say in your question "*required for `package X` to run*". So, what is your purpose ? Please check also [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Although, as I have written in **bold** if there is any other method to let `apt` tell me, if a package - other, than `package X` - is being installed from `repo 2`, it would answer my question. It is just that I could not think of a better alarm, than having `apt` complain about missing dependencies.

Comment: I do not think this is an XY problem, since I have explained my endgoal, and even added in **bold** that what I described may not be the best way to achieve this, so if anyone has a better idea, put that forward.

Comment: Then please fix your question to avoid confusion: "only package X is installable from there" vs "I want apt to tell me". The first is not advisable to do, hence my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt` pinning [can be made to work here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty#Standard_pinning). Add an entry such as

```
Package: *
Pin: origin repo2
Pin-Priority: 100
```

This will allow installation from `repo2`, but will ensure that packages present in both `repo1` and `repo2` prefer the `repo1` versions for upgrades. If a `repo2` version is required for another `repo2` package, `apt` can be asked to use it with the appropriate `-t` option. This is the same setup as used for backports repositories.

You’ll end up with the following behaviour:

```
$ sudo apt install moosefs-client/bullseye-backports
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '3.0.116-1~bpo11+1' (Debian Backports:bullseye-backports [amd64]) for 'moosefs-client'
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gconf2 libgsf-bin
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libmfsio1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmfsio1 moosefs-client
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
Need to get 504 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,580 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libmfsio1 amd64 3.0.115-1 [171 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports/main amd64 moosefs-client amd64 3.0.116-1~bpo11+1 [333 kB]
Fetched 504 kB in 0s (1,395 kB/s)       
...
```

I asked for the backported version of `moosefs-client`, and `apt` picked the default version of `libmfsio1` rather than the backported version. If I’d specified `-t bullseye-backports`, it would have picked both from backports. For a package only available in `repo2`, you wouldn’t need to specify `/repo2` at all; and if the package is uninstallable without pulling in other packages from `repo2` which have older versions in `repo1`, `apt` would fail unless you specified `-t repo2`.